# Convention for freeing C ADTs

Tags: c

When writing a free function for an ADT what is the convention for freeing the passed pointer?

```
void dropSet(Set s) {
   if (s == NULL) {
      return;
   }
   Node next, curr = s->elems;
   while (curr != NULL) {
      next = curr->next;
      dropNode(curr);
      curr = next;
   }
   free(s)   // <== Should this line be here or no?
   s = NULL; // <== Should this line be here or no?
}
```

** **Edit** **

The set is malloc'd by a function called newSet which is called by the user. Drop here means to dispose of the set. If free(s) is not called here it will be the next line called in main. I understand in an isolated implementation ultimately whichever way I do it makes no difference but as a convention in the wider community should I be freeing the pointer in this function and setting it to NULL or leaving it to the caller to free it where it's called from?

Comment: Was `s` allocated by `malloc` (or `calloc`)? Then yes you should probably `free` it *somewhere*.

Comment: So long as `s` is pointing at a dynamically allocated object, `free(s)` is fine :) Although, set does not look like a pointer, have you typedef'd it?

Comment: The set is malloc'd by a function called newSet which is called by main. Drop here means to dispose. Should I free the pointer in this function or leave it to the caller to dispose of it in main?

@George, it is a typedef'd pointer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That of course depends on what "drop" means for a Set. Does it mean "clear this Set, make it empty" or does it mean "delete this Set, it's no longer valid".

If it's the former, then the final `free()` should not be there, but otherwise it should.

Since "drop" (at least to me) is not clear, it's hard to answer this with certainty.

I would suggest renaming the function (to perhaps `freeSet()` or `deleteSet()`, or whatever the inverse of the function that creates a set would be) and documenting the semantics (i.e. what it does) to make it really clear. Then decide on the code.

Comment: If the final free() isn't called here it will be the next line in the calling function. By convention should the free be here or should it be in the calling function?

Comment: By convention it depends on name of function, this is what unwind explained to you. If function name suggests freeing, free. Moreover, is Set a typedef for a pointer? If yes, then you are making user more confused.

Comment: dropSet() is part of an ADT, the user will never "see" it.
Thank you for the clarity :)